# How can you show zero in a row using year and month dynamic in an interval?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query to show count when **SET YEAR and MONTH** at an interval of 12 months (the year and month are dynamic values - the interval is a static value of 12 months).

For example: **set month = 12 and year = 2013**

```
This will count from 2013-12-01 to 2014-11-30
```

Other example: **set month = 1 and year = 2014**

```
This will count from 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31
```

I created this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/28) but also want to show 0 when the rows's count are not in the table, here I used **COALESCE**:

```
SET @var_year = '2013';
SET @var_month = '12';

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d');
SET @to = DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 12 MONTH);

SELECT COALESCE(count(created_at), 0) AS count_all,
       year(created_at) as actual_year,
       month(created_at)as actual_month 
FROM creations
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to
GROUP BY month(created_at),year(created_at)
ORDER BY year(created_at),month(created_at) ASC
```

But unfortunately got this result:

```
count_all   actual_year actual_month
1               2013         12
3               2014          1
2               2014          2
1               2014          3
1               2014          4
1               2014          5
1               2014          6
2               2014          8
1               2014          9
1               2014         10
1               2014         11
```

I expect this result:

```
count_all   actual_year actual_month
1               2013         12
3               2014          1
2               2014          2
1               2014          3
1               2014          4
1               2014          5
1               2014          6
0               2014          7     <------ HERE I WANT 0 WHEN IS NOT IN DB
2               2014          8
1               2014          9
1               2014         10
1               2014         11
```

I created this [live demo using month = 12 and year = 2013](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/35), it actually works, but after **testing and changing month or year values, got bad counts**, so the query is not working correctly for example this [demo using month= 1 and year =2013 isn't working correctly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/36)

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '1';

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d');
SET @to = DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 12 MONTH);

SELECT IFNULL(counter,0) as counter, literals.y AS actual_year, literals.m AS actual_month
FROM (
  SELECT @var_month AS m, @var_year + 0 AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 1) % 12, (@var_month + 1) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 1) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 2) % 12, (@var_month + 2) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 2) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 3) % 12, (@var_month + 3) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 3) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 4) % 12, (@var_month + 4) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 4) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 5) % 12, (@var_month + 5) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 5) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 6) % 12, (@var_month + 6) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 6) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 7) % 12, (@var_month + 7) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 7) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 8) % 12, (@var_month + 8) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 8) DIV 12) AS y 
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 9) % 12, (@var_month + 9) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 9) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month +10) % 12, (@var_month +10) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month +10) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month +11) % 12, (@var_month +11) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month +11) DIV 12) AS y)  
  AS literals
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) as counter, year(created_at) y, month(created_at) as m 
   FROM creations WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to GROUP BY month(created_at),year(created_at)
   ORDER BY year(created_at),month(created_at) ASC 
 ) AS counts
 ON literals.m = counts.m AND literals.y = counts.y;
```

I spent months searching information about how to deal with this problem.

If somebody can help me, is it impossible to resolve or another trick or query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice puzzle :)

You can generate a table that will hold Year and Month needed for the 12 months interval and then, do an outer join on it :

```
SET @var_year = '2013'
SET @var_month = '12'

SELECT @row := @row + (case when right(@row,2) = "12" then 89 else 1 end) as YearMonth 
FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
 select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
 select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all 
 select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11) t,
(SELECT @row:=CONCAT(@var_year,right(concat('0',(@var_month-1)),2))) r
```

Will give :

```
| YearMonth |
|-----------|
|    201312 |
|    201401 |
|    201402 |
|    201403 |
|    201404 |
|    201405 |
|    201406 |
|    201407 |
|    201408 |
|    201409 |
|    201410 |
|    201411 |
```

So try this (example with 2014 as year and 1 as month) :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/58)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE creations(`id` int, `created_at` date )
;

INSERT INTO creations
    (`id`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    (1, '2013-12-11'),
    (2, '2014-01-11'),
    (3, '2014-01-21'),
    (4, '2014-01-12'),
    (5, '2014-02-22'),    
    (6, '2014-02-13'),
    (7, '2014-03-12'),    
    (8, '2014-04-23'),
    (9, '2014-05-23'),
    (10,'2014-06-23'),
    (11,'2014-08-23'),    
    (12,'2014-08-23'),
    (13,'2014-09-23'),
    (14,'2014-10-23'),    
    (15,'2014-11-23'),        
    (16,'2014-12-23')         
;
```

**Query **:

```
SET @var_year = '2014'
SET @var_month = '1'

SELECT count(created_at) AS count_all,
       left(YearMonth,4) as actual_year,
       right(YearMonth,2) as actual_month 
FROM (
SELECT @row := @row + (case when right(@row,2) = "12" then 89 else 1 end) as YearMonth FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
 select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
 select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all 
 select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11) t,
(SELECT @row:=CONCAT(@var_year,right(concat('0',(@var_month-1)),2))) r
) as YearMonthTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN creations ON
  CONCAT(year(created_at),right(concat('0',month(created_at)),2)) = YearMonth
GROUP BY YearMonth
ORDER BY YearMonth ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/58/2)**:

```
| count_all | actual_year | actual_month |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|         3 |        2014 |           01 |
|         2 |        2014 |           02 |
|         1 |        2014 |           03 |
|         1 |        2014 |           04 |
|         1 |        2014 |           05 |
|         1 |        2014 |           06 |
|         0 |        2014 |           07 |
|         2 |        2014 |           08 |
|         1 |        2014 |           09 |
|         1 |        2014 |           10 |
|         1 |        2014 |           11 |
|         1 |        2014 |           12 |
```

**EDITED :**

You can also create the table instead of generating it in a subquery every time :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/066f6f/2)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE YearMonthTable(`tblYear` int, `tblMonth` int)
;

INSERT INTO YearMonthTable
    (`tblYear`,`tblMonth`)
VALUES
    (2013,12),
    (2014,1),
    (2014,2),    
    (2014,3),    
    (2014,4),
    (2014,5),
    (2014,6),
    (2014,7),    
    (2014,8),
    (2014,9),
    (2014,10),    
    (2014,11),        
    (2014,12),
    (2015,1),
    (2015,2),    
    (2015,3),    
    (2015,4),
    (2015,5)
;
```

**Query**:

```
SET @var_year = '2014'
SET @var_month = '1'

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d')
SET @to = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL -1 DAY)

SELECT count(created_at) AS count_all,
       tblYear as actual_year,
       tblMonth as actual_month 
FROM YearMonthTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN creations ON year(created_at) = tblYear AND 
                             month(created_at) = tblMonth
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tblYear, '/', tblMonth, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') 
                                                    BETWEEN @from AND @to                               
GROUP BY tblMonth, tblYear
ORDER BY tblYear, tblMonth
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/066f6f/2/4)**:

```
| count_all | tblYear | tblMonth |
|-----------|---------|----------|
|         3 |    2014 |        1 |
|         2 |    2014 |        2 |
|         1 |    2014 |        3 |
|         1 |    2014 |        4 |
|         1 |    2014 |        5 |
|         1 |    2014 |        6 |
|         0 |    2014 |        7 |
|         2 |    2014 |        8 |
|         1 |    2014 |        9 |
|         1 |    2014 |       10 |
|         1 |    2014 |       11 |
|         1 |    2014 |       12 |
```

Comment: Nice job my friend. But is there any other way to resolve this? with less code? =)

Comment: Look at my EDITED answer to see a way of doing it with "less code" :)

Comment: Thanks @Fabien your last code worked too but I replaced year =2013 and month=1 should show ZEROS, I think your first code it's what I want =)

Comment: Anyways....EXCELENT JOB and thanks for helping me, I was trying to resolve this for several months. +1 , +MY THANKS.

Comment: This one show ZEROS, I changed the table to hold VARCHAR value instead http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7db6d0/1.... Feel stupid...you mean show ZEROS for each month with no data....for this...you need to add `2013,1....2013,2....2013,3....etc.` in the `YearMonthTable`

Comment: Ok... I will explain you the query...I wanted show 0 and I know is crazy here in this link http://jsfiddle.net/7e09b5u6/1/ I wanted show 0 because to continue the presentation in the graphic, for that reason I want show ZEROS, also years and months are dynamics.Your first query works perfect adding zeros.