# What is the name for aggregation queries that record zero-count records?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I see questions all the time (and perhaps a Meta post could be made about how to handle them) that follow the lines of:

> Get the count of [some field] for [some object].

Where the problem usually lies in:

```
SELECT myField, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myField;
```

Which will not return rows that have 0 counts, so it typically involves preforming an outer join back to the table to get those counts.

Is there a name for this type of procedure? Is it still just simply `Aggregation`? The reason I wonder if it's different, is because it involves using a join to aggregate data that *doesn't exist* in the table.

Also, I have heard of special types of aggregation such as `conditional aggregation`, so I thought there might be a term [slang, or standard] for this type of operation.

---

Edit, to explain what I meant by data that 'doesn't exist' consider a users table like this:

```
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
| 1  | John  |
| 2  | Bob   |
| 3  | Sandy |
| 4  | Time  |
```

And a login table like this:

```
| user_id | loginTime |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    | 01:43:44  |
|    1    | 02:43:44  |
|    3    | 03:43:44  |
|    3    | 04:43:44  |
|    3    | 05:43:44  |
|    4    | 06:43:44  |
```

If I want to get the total number of log ins for each user, I could do the following:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) AS numLogins
FROM users u 
JOIN login l ON l.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

However, this won't return a row for user 2 unless I use an outer join and the coalesce function. What is the name for this type of operation?

Comment: " because it involves using a join to aggregate data that doesn't exist in the table."...No data doesn't exist...data HAVE to exist....or it's not data...You said "Which will not return rows that have 0 counts"....0 counts of WHAT ? Answer this "what" and you will have the data that need to exist somewhere :) If you want an example, I recently answered a question about a similar case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082636/how-can-you-show-zero-in-a-row-using-year-and-month-dynamic-in-an-interval

Comment: Conditional aggregation is usually implemented with `CASE`, like `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN one_int ELSE another_int END)`.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution I understand what you're saying, I tried to clarify. Perhaps there *is no answer* to my question, but it's hard to google something like that. If there is a name for it, I don't know it, and in turn can't search it.

Comment: I do not believe there's a special name. It's just a simple OUTER JOIN with Aggregation.

Comment: @PM77-1 okay. Is a question like this appropriate? I think I've made my question pretty clear, and maybe it's anticlimactic if there's no answer, but I can't find anything to indicate this isn't the type of question that belongs on SO.

Comment: "unless I use an outer join and the coalesce function"...Only the `OUTER JOIN` is needed...no need to use `COALESCE` or `IFNULL`...So I say like @PM77-1...it's simply an outer join (a left in this case) with aggregation.

Comment: There is no special name because the problem is nothing to do with the aggregation. The query you have posted that omits user 2 would do so with or without an aggregate and group by. This is nothing more than understanding inner and outer joins. In the case of the first query with no join, again there is no special name for when data that does not exist is not returned from a query.

Comment: If there is a formal name, it might be found in *[SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596523084.do)*  Unfortunately, my copy was pilfered!

Comment: @McAdam331: it's quiet a weird question. If you can get the desired result with `JOIN` and `COUNT`, it's a statement with aggregation (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). What is your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Comment: I understood your question right away. So, yes it was clear to me.  This is, however, a pure *terminology* question, while on this site we are more accustomed to *how to* or *why* questions:  how to solve XYZ problem in ABC environment or what's wrong with such-and-such solution.

Comment: @PM77-1 You're right, I just didn't think about it as a 'terminology' question. I'm gonna search around on Meta because I am genuinely curious about this type of question, but I can also wait and see how the community takes it. Thanks for your help, also.

Comment: @PM77-1 and others, I have found an old MSE post about [nomenclature questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/what-is-the-appropriate-preferred-method-for-questions-concerning-programming) that has the consensus they are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you describe (very well) is typically referred to **sparse data**.

There's all sort of "how-to" suggestions/patterns for getting those "zero" counts returned out of sparse data.

The terms I've heard refer to **density**, and getting the data into a **dense** form.  (Getting the data "densified" (is that even a real word?), referring to that process as "densification" (I don't think that's a real word either.)

I believe I ran across those terms in the Oracle Data Warehousing Guide (Oracle documentation). Other vendors may use different vernacular. I don't know that there's any official standard term.

**EDIT**

Reference: Oracle "Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/analysis.htm#i1014934

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to use any and all variations of the word 'dense'. I have found this [article](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/data_modeling/dense_sparse) which I am still reading through, so I don't know *how* relevant it is, but it describes both dense and sparse in a similar way you do, and does apply pretty well to the question I've asked. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @McAdam331 As complement : http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/heckerman/ch99uai.pdf

Comment: @McAdam331: I added a reference to the Oracle "Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence" documentation. Those are the terms that they use. A I noted, the term **sparse data** is fairly common and standard across the industry and vendors. Ad for SQL to report those zero counts, we need to "fill the gaps". The term **dense data** may be appropriate. (I'm not as sure about those terms *densified* and *densification*.)